# Atualizar ProgressBar em segundo plano java android

Tags: java, android

Como que faço para o serviço em background atualizar o `ProgressBar` no `Android`?

Meu código:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // inicial o progressbar
            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
            progressBar.setCancelable(true);
            progressBar.setMessage("Exportando os dados...");
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            progressBar.show();

// Inicia o serviço a partir de INICIAR_SERVICO definido no

    startService(new Intent("INICIAR_SERVICO"));
```

Não estou sabendo usar o `progressBar.setProgress();` na class do serviço chamado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O serviço não pode chamar `progressBar.setProgress()` diretamente. Ele precisa dar um jeito de solicitar à `Activity` visível nesse momento que esse método seja chamado.

Vejo duas possibilidades: a primeira, que não é minha preferida por ser um pouco mais complicada, é se acoplar (bind) ao serviço e assim permitir que o serviço se comunique com a `Activity` em questão. Para isso deve-se passar ao serviço a referência a um `listener` que o serviço vai chamando cada vez que o `progress` deva ser aumentado. Na `Activity`, o `listener` executa `progressBar.setProgress()`. A documentação explica como fazer para [se acoplar a um serviço](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

A segunda, que eu prefiro, é transmitir atualizações de `progress` via broadcast. Você registra um `BroadcastReceiver` associado ao ciclo de vida de sua `Activity` (por exemplo, é feito o `registerReceiver()` em `onResume()` e o `unregisterReceiver()` em `onPause()` - uma dúvida minha aqui, não tenho certeza se os melhores métodos para isso são o par `onResume()/onPause()` ou `onStart()/onStop()`). E quando a `Activity` recebe um `broadcast intent` contendo o novo valor de `progress`, chama `progressBar.setProgress()`.

Código no qual você pode se basear:

### MinhaActivity.java:

```
public class MinhaActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private IntentFilter mFilter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mFilter.addAction("ATUALIZA_PROGRESSO");
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if ("ATUALIZA_PROGRESSO".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                mProgressBar.setProgress(intent.getIntExtra("progress"));
                if (intent.getIntExtra("progress") >= 100) {
                    mProgressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    mProgressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
    mProgressBar.setCancelable(true);
    mProgressBar.setMessage("Exportando os dados...");
    mProgressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
    mProgressBar.setMax(100);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // inicia o progressbar
    mProgressBar.show();

    // Inicia o serviço
    startService(new Intent(this, MeuServico.class));
}

protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, mFilter);
}

protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

### MeuService.java

```
public class MeuService extends IntentService {
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        while (tarefaNaoTerminada) {
            (...)
            Intent intentAEnviar = new Intent("ATUALIZA_PROGRESSO");
            intentAEnviar.putExtra("progress", progresso);
            sendBroadcast(intentAEnviar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ótimo! é isso que eu preciso Piovezan, muito obrigado.

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos Que bom que ajudou. Se a resposta for o que você precisava, pode aceitá-la.